# Need enhancement on android mapview overlays

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mapview

I'm trying to run a specific code that regularly adds/removes markers on a map, I tried the AsyncTask approach instead of thread and runnable,

in the doInBackground :

```
mapView.getOverlays.remove()
mapView.getOverlays.addOverlay(new overlay)
mapView.getController.animate(center point)
```

actual problem is, that code runs continuously and while executing map gets rendering and tries to get overlays to draw, while the code is removing and adding into the list, so ConcurrentModificationException is thrown and the application halts

I need help about it, I feel that I'm on the wrong path, what really should I use when trying to run code in background thread that updates regularly markers on the map ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to render the points all in one go like slkorolev suggested, use the UI handler mechanism.

---

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {  
publicvoid handleMessage(Message msg) {   
switch (msg.what) {   
case TestHandler.NEW_OVERLAY_ITEM_EVENT:   
mapView.getOverlays.remove()
mapView.getOverlays.addOverlay(new overlay)
mapView.getController.animate(center point)  
break;   
               }   
super.handleMessage(msg);   
          }   
     };
```

---

```
// post this UI update event 
Message message = new Message();   
message.what = TestHandler.NEW_OVERLAY_ITEM_EVENT;       
TestHandler.this.myHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

Comment: I tried your approach as well and I found it very helpful, in fact it solved the whole issue :)

Answer (score 1):

UI is not thread safe so you must not update ui components from non-main thread. AsyncTask has mthods which are called from the main thread. The idea is to prepare all the data in `doInBackgraound` and then update UI in `postExecute` method.

Comment: that's great, but how should I run the task repeatedly again and again, this is where I'm stuck

Comment: @Smartdog: As AsyncTask can only be executed only once you have to instantiate it each time you need a background calculation. There is also a good review of other methods [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: I've read this topic a lot around the web, but it gave me much less than what I want, anyway I developed another workaround that did what I really want, thanks anyway for you concern and time

Comment: @Smartdog: Thanks for accepting. AsyncTask really worked for me in a way "implement-and-forget" also in a similar scenario - I need to update map overlay once user taps a button.

Comment: I may try it, it should be much more efficient than that I implemented